# Image sometimes does not display in HTML page (Django 3.0)

Tags: javascript, html, django

I created a somewhat clone of Instagram main page (for full transparency, please know that I do this for a psychological experiment).

One of my users got a very strange bug : when going on my page, two images seemed to not be loaded (there was no broken link, and the images simply appeared to be skipped, see illustration below).

[Images not displaying illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKR1N.png)

On reloading the page, the images indeed appeared normally, and other users did not get any bug.

The thing is, I do not quite understand how this could happen, since I show the page only when all resources are loaded, through these lines of code :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById("main-page").style.visibility = "visible";
});
```

Please find the code for the page below (I removed navbar code for lisibility, please let me know if full version is needed).

```
<body id="main-page" style="visibility:hidden">

    <section class="main">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="left-col">
                {% include 'instapp/status.html' %}
                {% include 'instapp/post.html' %}
            </div>
            <div class="right-col">
                {% include 'instapp/recommandations.html' %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script>

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            document.getElementById("main-page").style.visibility = "visible";
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

And here is the code for displaying a single post :

```
{% load static %}
<div class="post">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="user">
            <div class="profile-pic"><img src='{% static instapost.name %}' alt=""></div>
            <p class="username">{{instapost.pseudo}}</p>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'img/3-vertical-dots.png' %}" class="options mobile" alt="" style="display:none">
        <img src="{% static 'img/option.PNG' %}" class="options desktop" alt="" style="display:none">
    </div>
    <img src='{% static instapost.name %}' class="post-image" alt="">
    <div class="post-content">
        <div class="reaction-wrapper">
            {% include 'instapp/post_icons.html' %}
        </div>
        <p class="likes">{{instapost.likes}} J'aime</p>
        <p class="description"><span>{{instapost.pseudo}} </span> {{instapost.comment|safe}}</p>
        <p class="post-time">{{instapost.time}}</p>
    </div>
    <hr class="comment_desc_sep">
    <div class="comment-wrapper">
        <img src="{% static 'img/smile.PNG' %}" class="icon" alt="">
        <input type="text" class="comment-box" placeholder="Ajouter un commentaire">
        <button class="comment-btn">Publier</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do you know what may cause this "bug" ?

I ran into a tutorial about detecting when images are all loaded (see [here](https://www.seancdavis.com/posts/wait-until-all-images-loaded/)). Do you think this can improve my situation ? As you may expect, this bug is unfortunately hard to replicate.

Thanks for your help !

Best,
Jessica

Answer (score 0):

Search `settings.py` into the project folder and create Variables like this.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]

STATIC_ROOT = 'mtg-django/static'
```

Comment: Hi Asif, thank you for your answer ! These variables are already set in my settings.py file, so I don't believe the issue comes from there.

Comment: Most of the time the error comes from the directory path. Make sure it's all okay. Check the html for the path again. Then do ``` python manage.py collectstatic``` . Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank for your answer ! Path is okay, as I said images did not display only one time. When the user reloaded the page, the images displayed normally. It just seems to me that the images somewhat failed to load the first time.